# Characterisation of faithful simple modules of primitive ring

Tags: ring-theory, d-modules

I am trying to prove the following:
[image]

$M$ is a simple $R$-module iff $M\cong R/\mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ -- does that help?

Am I up to finding an explicit isomorphism?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.